# Ansible set variable depending on which inventory I use

Tags: ansible

I want to set a variable called `orc_user` depending on which inventory I use. There is one test and one production environment.

I though about something like

```
if environment = test.yaml; orc_user = orchestration-test-user ||
if environment = production.yaml; orc_user = orchestration-prod-user
```

Is there any way to achieve this without setting this in the inventory? I really need this to be depending on which inventory file I am using.

Comment: What is wrong with setting it in the inventory? This is really the best solution to have it depending on which inventory you use.

Comment: Its not wrong, but i want to keep such things out of the inventory if its possible.

Comment: If it's dependent on the inventory, its place should be in the inventory. Note that when using tools like awx/tower, the inventory file/dir name is usually not under your control.

Comment: You could probably use the [special variable `inventory_file`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html) for that. But, as pointed by @Zeitounator, there is no valuable reason I see to not expose a variable in the inventory, rather.

Comment: @Zeitounator thanks. In the end i did it like you suggested :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about the tasks of "playbook", "role" and "inventory" in Ansible.

The inventory defines an environment. It is the "dynamic" part of your environments. Depending on the tasks of your inventory you can define not only hosts but "conditions" like what environment is it, what hosts are in, what software packages and what versions should be installed.

The "role" is something that creates a "state". It's task is - depending on the definition in the inventory to create the state inside the hosts

And the playbooks brings that all together. A dynamic inventory that can change often and assign a role to a list of hosts from that inventory.

Of course that is a very easy view. But as @Zeitounator already mentioned. There should be a variable in you inventory. The the "standard".

Comment: Hey, sorry guys, i need to come back to you. As @Zeitounator mentioned, I decided to define the variables in my inventory as follows:

`all:
  hosts:
    airflow.vagrant:
      ansible_host: 127.0.0.1
      ansible_port: 2222
      ansible_user: root
          
  vars:
    airflow_orc_user: userxyz
    airflow_orc_group: groupxyz`

despite this, my playbook uses the variables defined in /role/airflow/defaults/main.yaml and i dont get why :-/

Comment: Can you update your question or make a new question? The syntax for comments is very limited. Especially I miss the information, what variable seems to be wrong and what is in defaults/main.yml and what is the task where you use the variable. Beside that - the question was with `orc_user` and your comment says `airflow_orc_user` which is not the same.

Comment: You need to move them from `defaults/main.yml` to `vars/main.yml`. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence